# Updating GEO my WP fields using frontend Advanced custom fields form - WordPress

Tags: wordpress, insert, custom-post-type, advanced-custom-fields, geo

I’ve created a frontend form using the advanced custom fields (ACF) plugin. Within this form I’ve added some location fields such as postcode and city.

Below is the function used to update the post

```
global $post_id;
add_filter('acf/pre_save_post' , 'tsm_do_pre_save_post' );

function tsm_do_pre_save_post( $post_id ) {

 // Bail if not logged in or not able to post
 if ( ! ( is_user_logged_in() ) ) {
 return;
 }

 // check if this is to be a new post
 if( $post_id != 'new_job' ) {
 return $post_id;
}

$profile_id = um_profile_id();
$userID = 'user_'.$profile_id;

$user_id = get_current_user_id();

    // Create a new post
    $post = array(
       'ID'=> $post_id,
       'post_type' => 'members', 
       'post_status' => 'publish', 
       'post_title' => $userID, 
       'post_author' => $user_id,
       'category' => $_POST['acf']['field_594d0ffc2a66d'],
    );

 // insert the post
 $post_id = wp_insert_post( $post );

 // Save the fields to the post
 do_action( 'acf/save_post' , $post_id );

 return $post_id;
     exit;
}
```

Once this form has been submitted, the custom post type is updated with no issues.

How can I add the submitted location data (postcode, city etc) into the [GEO MY WP](https://geomywp.com/) information for the post?

I’ve tried to follow the information in the docs secetion (http://docs.geomywp.com/gmw_pt_update_location/) but not having much luck.

GEO my WP function fron docs below:

```
function gmw_update_post_type_post_location(  $post_id ) {

// Return if it's a post revision
if ( false !== wp_is_post_revision( $post_id ) )
    return;

// check autosave //
if ( defined( 'DOING_AUTOSAVE' ) && DOING_AUTOSAVE ) {
    return;
}

//check if user can edit post
if ( !current_user_can( 'edit_post', $post_id ) )
    return;

//get the address from the custom field "address"
$address = get_post_meta( $post_id, 'address', true );

//varify that address exists. Otherwise abort the function.
if ( empty( $address ) )
    return;

//include the update location file file
include_once( GMW_PT_PATH .'/includes/gmw-pt-update-location.php' );

//make sure the file included and the function exists
if ( !function_exists( 'gmw_pt_update_location' ) )
    return;

//Create the array that will pass to the function
$args = array(
        'post_id' => $post_id, //Post Id of the post 
        'address' => $address // the address we pull from the custom field above
);

//run the udpate location function
gmw_pt_update_location( $args );
}
//execute the function whenever post type is being updated
add_action( 'save_post_post', 'gmw_update_post_type_post_location' );
```

I believe I need to somehow combine the two functions so when the ACF form is updated, it also needs to update the GEO my wp meta data also.

I've tried combining the two functions but not having much luck.

If someone can point me in the right direction it will be very much appreciated

Thanks

Updated code.....

I've tried to add the gmw_update_post_type_post_location() function within the ACF function (code below) but still not having much luck...

```
global $post_id;
add_filter('acf/pre_save_post' , 'tsm_do_pre_save_post' );
function tsm_do_pre_save_post( $post_id ) {

 // Bail if not logged in or not able to post
 if ( ! ( is_user_logged_in() ) ) {
 return;
 }

 // check if this is to be a new post
 if( $post_id != 'new_job' ) {
 return $post_id;
 }

$profile_id = um_profile_id();
$userID = 'user_'.$profile_id;

$user_id = get_current_user_id();

$profilePostcode = get_post_meta( $post_id, 'location_postcode', true );

    // Create a new post
    $post = array(
       'ID'=> $post_id,
       'post_type' => 'members', // Your post type ( post, page, custom post type )
       'post_status' => 'publish', // You can use -> publish, draft, private, etc.
       'post_title' => $userID, // Post Title ACF field key
       'post_author' => $user_id,
       'category' => $_POST['acf']['field_594d0ffc2a66d'], // Post Content ACF field key
    );

 // insert the post
 $post_id = wp_insert_post( $post );

 // Save the fields to the post
 do_action( 'acf/save_post' , $post_id );

gmw_update_post_type_members_location($post_id);

 return $post_id;

 exit;
}

function gmw_update_post_type_members_location(  $post_id ) {

    $profilePostcode = get_post_meta( $post_id, 'profile_location_postcode', true );

    if ( empty( $profilePostcode ) )
        return;


    $address = array(
        //'street'   => $_POST['location_address'],
        //'city'     => $_POST['location_town'],
        //'state'    => $_POST['location_state'],
        'zipcode'  => $profilePostcode,
        //'country'  => $_POST['location_country']
    ); 

    include_once( GMW_PT_PATH .'/includes/gmw-pt-update-location.php' );

    if ( !function_exists( 'gmw_pt_update_location' ) )
        return;

    $profile_id = um_profile_id();
    $userID = 'user_'.$profile_id;

    $user_id = get_current_user_id();

    $args = array(
        'post_id' => $post_id, //Post Id of the post
        'post_title' => $userID, // Post Title ACF field key
        'post_author' => $user_id,
        'post_type' => 'members', 
        'address' => $address

    );

    //run the udpate location function
    gmw_pt_update_location( $args );            
}
```

Comment: Hi, did you found a solution to it? I would be interested! Thank you